# After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, new icon with encrypted SSD

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, ssd

I recently upgraded from 20 to 22. I suddenly have an icon on my left bar which says SSD and a lock on it.

When I click it, it asks me for a password for an encrypted drive. It says there 91 GB of data encrypted. Not sure where this came from!

I have dual boot with windows 10.

Thanks!

Edit:

Command: `lsblk -f`

```
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/bare/5
loop1
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/246
loop2
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/248
loop3
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core/16091
loop4
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core/16202
loop5
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core18/2790
loop6
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core18/2796
loop7
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core20/1974
loop8
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core20/2015
loop9
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core22/858
loop10
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core22/864
loop11
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/cups/974
loop12
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/cups/980
loop13
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/deja-dup/567
loop14
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/deja-dup/572
loop15
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/firefox/3504
loop16
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/flutter/130
loop17
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/flutter/141
loop18
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
loop19
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop20
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/126
loop21
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
loop22
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop23
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop24
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/inkscape/10549
loop25
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/inkscape/10555
loop26
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/onlyoffice-desktopeditors/174
loop27
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/onlyoffice-desktopeditors/176
loop28
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snap-store/638
loop29
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snap-store/959
loop30
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd/20092
loop31
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd/20290
loop32
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
loop33
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/vlc/3078
loop34
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/vlc/3721
nvme0n1
│                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p1
│    vfat   FAT32 SYSTEM
│                       0D-20                             202.8M    21% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2
│                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p3
│    BitLoc 2                                                               
├─nvme0n1p4
│    ntfs         WinRE_DRV
│                       E6CCF0B2CCF07E5D                                    
└─nvme0n1p5
     ext4   1.0         fd77-1-4e-b6-5c13  232.9G    34% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                   /
```

Command: `cat /etc/fstab/`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=fd77-21-8e-b6-5c13 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=0D-80  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Also, looking at the partition, it seems the encrypted partition is BitLocker.

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to include the output of the command `lsblk -f` at the terminal, formatted as a "code block" to ensure it can be read correctly. That command lists the block devices - roughly, the storage devices - and their partitions, filesystems and sizes currently visible on your device.

It would also be helpful to post the output of `cat /etc/fstab` in the same way.

Thanks,

Comment: @johnandmegh updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "FSTYPE" column in that `lsblk` output indicates that you have a BitLocker-encrypted Windows partition - so that would be what you're seeing on the Ubuntu dock (what's on the left side of your screen).

If you just want icons like that to go away, then you can:

- Go to Settings (press <kbd>Super</kbd>, type Settings, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or select it from the screen
- On the left-hand side, scroll to "Appearance" ("Ubuntu Desktop" on 23.10) and click that
- On the right-hand side, look for the "Dock" section, then the line "Configure dock behavior", and click that
- In the pop-up options box, deselect/uncheck what you want here - if you want all additional drives/devices to no longer show, then switch off "Show Volumes and Devices". If you just want unmounted volumes to be hidden, like your Windows partition, then uncheck "Include Unmounted Volumes"

If you want to actually access your BitLocker encrypted partition from within Ubuntu, [that's a whole other process](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-mount-bitlocker-encrypted.html), although it is doable.

Hope this helps

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!
Just one minor thing, there was no Ubuntu Desktop. It was under Appearance.

Comment: D'oh, thanks for the correction - I was taking the lazy way out and was just referencing my personal installation of 23.10! Glad it helped